# What is the best way to get values with a key and multiple hashes?

Tags: redis, servicestack

There is a code in ServiceStack.Redis:

```
public List<string> GetValuesFromHash(string hashId, params string[] keys)
    {
        if (keys.Length == 0) return new List<string>();
        var keyBytes = ConvertToBytes(keys);
        var multiDataList = base.HMGet(hashId, keyBytes);
        return multiDataList.ToStringList();
    }
```

I need

```
public List<string> GetValuesFromHashes(string key, params string[] hashIds)
```

How can I implement it? I tried to add to ServiceStack Redis but a little confused.

Any idea?